# Create Scratch Org with specific Territory2Settings

Tags: scratch-org, territory-management, scratch-org-definition-file

I am trying to create a scratch org with Territory2 enabled, as we have this in our production org and I want to mimic it as good as possible.

The full documentation for this metadata can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_territory2settings.htm).

I have set up the scratch org definition to enable Territory2, however I am unsure what values to add to the other parameters. I am referring to:

- `defaultAccountAccessLevel`
- `defaultCaseAccessLevel`
- `defaultContactAccessLevel`
- `defaultOpportunityAccessLevel`
- `t2ForecastAccessLevel`

According to the page referenced above, the field type is "string", however I cannot find any information about what string would related to which value in the settings. For example, for Account we have the following options:

> Users in a territory can:
>
> 1. View accounts assigned to
> 2. the territory   View and edit accounts assigned to the territory
> 3. View, edit, transfer, and delete accounts assigned to the territory

What string value would relate to each of these options?

Reference scratch org json below:

```json
{
  "orgName": "Sample Org",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "language": "en_US",
  "hasSampleData": true,
  "settings": {
      "territory2Settings": {
        "enableTerritoryManagement2": true,
        "defaultAccountAccessLevel": ????,
        "defaultCaseAccessLevel": ????,
        etc...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to config all those parameters ?  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/51/Territory2/scratch-def/developer

Comment: Yes, as I am trying to deploy source that requires these to be set up correctly. Either way, what I am asking for are the possible values for those parameters for the metadata api, it does not have to be specific for scratch orgs. I find it strange that the potential values are not listed in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comment by @sfdxfox I retried the data from an org where I manually set the different values in the GUI.

For future reference for anyone having this issue, here are the possible values (separated by a comma, in top-to-bottom order of possible alternatives in the GUI):

```json
"territory2Settings": {
        "enableTerritoryManagement2": true,false
        "defaultAccountAccessLevel": "Read","Edit","All",
        "defaultCaseAccessLevel": "None","Read","Edit",
        "defaultContactAccessLevel": "Edit",????,
        "defaultOpportunityAccessLevel": "None","Read","Edit",
        "t2ForecastAccessLevel": "Read","Edit"
    }
```

Interestingly, I found no way of changing `defaultContactAccessLevel` in the GUI so I do not know the other possible values to this option (if there are any)

I found the full list of values: [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_territory2.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There is a further bit of documentation, just in a [different place](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_territory2settings.htm).

However, it seems to also be incomplete. Your best option is to retrieve these settings from an existing org, then use those values in the JSON configuration file:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Settings:Territory2 -u production
```

Using the values from the mdapi output is your best option to make sure the values are correct. The two in the documentation appear to be `Read` and `Edit`, the others are not so clear, and I don't have an org set up with this to test.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a good way forward. I'll retrieve the values and post them here for future reference.